# Xamarin forms CrossMedia.Current asking permission

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I am developing a xamarin forms application which access device camera and gallery to take pictures. I am using the following code

```
CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(new StoreCameraMediaOptions
                {
                    SaveToAlbum = true,
                    Name = string.Format(TDJGolfConstants.ProfileImageName, Guid.NewGuid()),
                    //AllowCropping = true,
                    //CompressionQuality = 60,
                    PhotoSize= PhotoSize.Medium,
```

But it is not asking the user for permission , and directly opens the camera and gallery. Is there anything to add for asking permisision?

Comment: May be this should be helpful to you: https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/general/projects/add_permissions_to_android_manifest/  and 
 https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/81218/takephotoasync-asks-user-for-permission-but-doesnt-open-camera-on-android

Answer (score 0):

I use [CrossPermissions from the PermissionsPlugin](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/PermissionsPlugin) for this

```
var status = await CrossPermissions.Current.CheckPermissionStatusAsync(Permission.Camera);
if (status != PermissionStatus.Granted)
{
    if (await CrossPermissions.Current.ShouldShowRequestPermissionRationaleAsync(Permission.Camera))
    {
        await UserNotificationService.Current.Show("Camera required", "justification");
    }

    var results = await CrossPermissions.Current.RequestPermissionsAsync(Permission.Camera);
```